# Setting x-axis manually

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to make 5 line plots, first should just include values from year 1960 and 5 dots (one for each country), next plot should include values from years 1960 and 1961 and line connecting values for each country, etc. Last plot should include values from all years. But I want x-axis to be constant from 1960 to 1964.

```
Country Name    1960        1961        1962        1963        1964
Pakistan        44.98869    46.065231   47.198878   48.387301   49.627623
Indonesia       87.751068   90.098394   92.518377   95.015297   97.596733
United States   180.671     183.691     186.538     189.242     191.889
India           450.547679  459.642165  469.07719   478.825608  488.848135
China           667.07      660.33      665.77      682.335     698.355
```

This is nicely doing line plots, however I have troubles with setting x-axis, command  `ax.set_xlim(1960,1964)` is not doing anything good, can someone help?

```
years=list((range(1960,1965)))
for i in years:
    yearsi=list((range(1960,i+1)))
    yearsi=map(str,yearsi)
    ax=newdf.pivot_table(values=yearsi, columns='Country Name').plot()
    ax.set_ylim([0, 700])
```

Comment: Is the call to `ax.set_xlim(1960, 1964)` inside the loop our outside?

Comment: Inside the loop, as loop is for different plots and I want all of them to have x-axis from 1960 to 1964

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the years you provide are strings and not integers. The correct `xlim` is just `range(0, 5)`. The final two lines also set the `xticks` and `xticklabels` correctly.

```
years = list((range(1960,1965)))
for i in years:
    yearsi = list((range(1960, i+1)))
    yearsi = map(str, yearsi)
    ax = df.pivot_table(values=yearsi, columns='Country Name').plot()
    ax.set_ylim([0, 700])
    ax.set_xticks(range(5))
    ax.set_xticklabels(range(1960, 1966))
```